# Apply plus function in Clojure

Tags: clojure, apply

Any idea why

```
(+ nil ) ;-> returns nil

(apply + nil) ;-> return 0 ?
```

thank you very much

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two cases are different.

In the case of `(+ nil)`, the nil argument is in place of a number. In the case of `(apply + nil)`, the nil is in place of a list of numbers.

The equivalent of

```
user> (+ nil)
nil
```

using apply would be

```
user> (apply + '(nil))
nil
```

which returns the same result.

On the other hand, by calling `(apply + nil)`, you are calling `+` on an empty list, in other words calling `+` with no arguments, which returns 0. The following are all equivalent:

```
user> (+)
0    
user> (apply + nil)
0
user> (apply + '())
0
```

Answer (score 1):

`(apply + nil)` means "use no arguments" which is equivalent to just `(+)`.

```
(+)
=> 0
```

[See source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/db94999b543effe0be04ca4ed53d8e699674cfff/src/jvm/clojure/lang/AFn.java#L150)

Comment: FWIW `(apply + '(nil))` returns `nil`